# Xcode: storing/retrieving data in plist after renaming not working anymore

Tags: xcode, plist

Today I created a project with local data storage (plist). Everything worked fine until I renamed my plist-file (from: Log.plist to: Data.plist). I renamed it inside Xcode, so there's no wrong connection.

What could it be? I already cleared Xcode, removed all files in DerivedData, but noting works. The data won't get saved in my plist-file.

Also tried to recreate the project with another name or restore the files from Time Capsule: Every time I rename the plist, nothing gets stored anymore.

Does anyone have an idea why no data gets stored? Thanks for your time.

### EDIT

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self retrieveDataFromPlist:@"Data"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger results = tableViewData.count;

    return results;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"logDataCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)retrieveDataFromPlist:(NSString *)plist
{
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", plist]];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plist ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    NSData *plistData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *plistError;
    NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&plistFormat errorDescription:&plistError];

    if (!plistDictionary) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving data from plist: %@", plistError);
    }

    tableViewData = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"Logs"];

    [self.logTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)storeData:(NSString *)data inPlist:(NSString *)plist
{
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", plist]];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plist ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    NSMutableArray *refreshedTableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];

    for (int i = 0; i < tableViewData.count; i++) {
        [refreshedTableData addObject:[tableViewData objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [refreshedTableData insertObject:data atIndex:0];

    // remove last object after 25 logs to keep storage as small as possible
    if (refreshedTableData.count > 25) {
        [refreshedTableData removeLastObject];
    }

    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshedTableData, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Logs", nil]];
    NSString *plistError;
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&plistError];

    if (plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error storing data in plist: %@", plistError);
    }

    // retrieve refreshed data so tableView is always filled with the latest logs
    [self retrieveDataFromPlist:@"Data"];
}

- (void)deleteFullPlist:(NSString *)plist
{

}

- (IBAction)menuButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController slideRight];
}

- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self storeData:self.textfield.text inPlist:@"Data"];
}
```

Comment: 1) You need to provide the code. 2) You need to use Git so you can track your changes. 3) Look in the Documents directory and see if the file is there, if so open and verify the contents. 4) Look at any error returns.

Comment: 1) Code added 2) should be activated but I don't know how to use this new feature 3) file is there and content seems to be ok 4) no error until now

Comment: re Git: learn to use it, watch the Apple WWDC video. Using source control is part of any development effort, even for one person. It will save you countless hours after a couple of bad changes. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to save the plist to the app's bundle.

```
- (void)storeData:(NSString *)data inPlist:(NSString *)plist {
    ...
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plist ofType:@"plist"];
    }
```

Remove the last 3 lines above, you always need to store in the Document directory.

Comment: Zaph... you're GREAT. Thank you so much. Spent hours on this.. May I pay you a beer? :)